# need help on simple java dictionary!

Tags: java

i want to write a simple java dictionary that use a hash table but i don't know how i should do that. if somebody have a simple code that can help me complete my project please notify me or help me because my dead line on this project is on thursday and I am really new in java.

Comment: what you mean by Java dictionary? like a HashMap?

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework/coursework..?

Comment: What have you been taught on this?

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
```

k = key 
v = value 
can be any object

Answer (score 1):

So given the existence of the [`HashMap` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), what more help do you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
   numbers.put("one", 1);
   numbers.put("two", 2);
   numbers.put("three", 3);
```